# log4j: timezone formatting

Tags: java, timezone, log4j

I would like to format the timezone information in log4j messages in the format
`+hh:mm` such that a complete timestamp looks like this:

```
2013-09-05T09:32:10.703+02:00
```

I know the date format specifier `Z`, but then the output format is `+hhmm` and not `+hh:mm`. So the colon is missing:

```
2013-09-10T15:55:34.123+0200
```

Is there any way to get what I want?

Comment: upload your log4j.xml or log4j.properties

Answer (score 14):

Uses the following pattern:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

In the javadoc of [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you can read that (for the `X` letter):

> **ISO 8601 Time zone**: The number of pattern letters designates the format for both formatting and parsing as follows:

```
ISO8601TimeZone:
        OneLetterISO8601TimeZone
        TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone
        ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone
OneLetterISO8601TimeZone:
        Sign TwoDigitHours
        Z
TwoLetterISO8601TimeZone:
        Sign TwoDigitHours Minutes
        Z
ThreeLetterISO8601TimeZone:
        Sign TwoDigitHours : Minutes
        Z
```

e.g.

```
X       -08; 
XX      -0800; 
XXX     -08:00
```

---

If your configuration file is the `log4j.xml`, can be as follows:

```
<!-- console -->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="threshold" value="TRACE" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="conversionPattern"
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX} %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And if you have a Java class with:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("Test");
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
2013-09-12T08:08:18.532-05:00 INFO  (Main.java:8).main - Test
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I had just found the Web page documenting the SimpleDateFormat for version 1.4.2 and there the "X" was not supported yet. And unfortunately we are using Java 6 and there also the "X" is not supported yet.

Comment: Hi Paul,  does yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX uses UTC time zone ?

Comment: Hi, @SumalathaAbhishek Nope. It's only for the format.

Comment: Hi @PaulVargas, I used XXX as you wrote. In windows environment I get the date with "+00:03" as I need. But in linux environment I get something strange. In the end of the time I get "Z" without "+00:03". Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I am using PatternLayout with logback-classic-1.2.3.jar and below date pattern gives me Sydney timezone, you need to update according to GMT

```
"timestamp":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, GMT+10}"
```